# Scrapy Not Finding div.title

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

```
import scrapy


class BookSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "books"
    start_urls = [
        'http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/page-1.html'
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        page = response.url.split(".")[-1]
        filename = f'BooksHTML-{page}.html'
        with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(response.body)
        self.log(f'Saved file {filename}')
```

So I am using this spider to practice webscraping and I am trying to collect all the titles of the books on this page. When I go into terminal and enter

> scrapy shell 'http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/page-1.html'

and then

> response.css("div.title").getall()

it only returns an empty list.

> []

Any clarification would be appreciated.

Comment: The answer is right.  That page does not contain any <div> tags with class 'title'.  Have you looked at the source?  I suspect you want the <a> tags that contain a 'title' attribute.  That's a different query, and doesn't involve css.

Comment: So how would I retrieve the title then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like [Tim Roberts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66463879/scrapy-not-finding-div-title/66465652#comment117500100_66463879) has pointed out in the comments, there are no divs with a `class` of `title`.

The full title of each book on the page is in the `title` property of an `a` tag (anchor tag), where the anchor tag links to a page for that specific book.

You could get the value of the `title` property for all anchor tags that have a `title` property like this:

```
response.css("a::attr(title)").getall()
```

returns:

```
['A Light in the Attic', 'Tipping the Velvet', 'Soumission', 'Sharp Objects', 'Sapiens: A Brief History of Humankind', 'The Requiem Red', 'The Dirty Little Secrets of Getting Your Dream Job', 'The Coming Woman: A Novel Based on the Life of the Infamous Feminist, Victoria Woodhull', 'The Boys in the Boat: Nine Americans and Their Epic Quest for Gold at the 1936 Berlin Olympics', 'The Black Maria', 'Starving Hearts (Triangular Trade Trilogy, #1)', "Shakespeare's Sonnets", 'Set Me Free', "Scott Pilgrim's Precious Little Life (Scott Pilgrim #1)", 'Rip it Up and Start Again', 'Our Band Could Be Your Life: Scenes from the American Indie Underground, 1981-1991', 'Olio', 'Mesaerion: The Best Science Fiction Stories 1800-1849', 'Libertarianism for Beginners', "It's Only the Himalayas"]
```

Comment: so the correct syntax is

response.ccs("HtmlTag.ClassName SubTag::attr(AttributeName)").getall()

?

Comment: `css` instead of `ccs`, but apart from that, yes that is correct. *The syntax of what you tried in your question was also correct, there just weren't any elements matching the selector*.

Comment: or just use [title]

Comment: @QHarr You're right the article is unnecessary for finding the title, thanks for pointing that out. I've adjusted my answer.